# Extract address from RSS Feed description

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have an RSS feed and the items are like this:

> Place: Starbucks
>
> Address: Example Street
>
> Date: 31/05 22:10 - 17/06 22:38

How can I extract the address from all feed items and create a new string only with the address in Yahoo Pipes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1. Use the **Rename** operator to make a copy of the `description` field to a `work` field
2. Use the **Regex** operator to extract the address part with a regular expression, for example replacing `.*Address: ([^\n]+).*` with `$1`

I put together an example pipe to demonstrate the technique:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a7f3d9e85f006e3f6c021c45dbb7ed38